# Access Elements of BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am receiving an array from my data.service.ts, and want to know how to access it. I am currently just printing it in the console to try and understand it, however I am unsure how to do anything with the data in the array.

Click link below to view data format in console:

[Observable BehaviorSubject Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/casoa.png)

Inside my footer.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent {

  nominations = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 
    this.nominations.push(this.dataService.currentNoms);
  }
```

footer.component.html:

```
<div id="podiums" *ngFor="let nom of nominations">
    <img src="{{nom.Poster}}">
</div>
```

I am trying to access the Poster attribute of each element and display the image associated with that poster, however when I inspect the page, the src for the image is unknown:
[img src unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0syB1.png)

**EDIT**

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private finalNoms = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentNoms = this.finalNoms.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addNominations(nom: Object){
    this.finalNoms.next(nom);
  }

}
```

Nominations Array:
[Nominations Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWDDq.png)

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it. New to Angular!

Comment: Can you post your DataService code? I dont know what currentNoms is.

Comment: Added the data service code. From some of the research I have been doing, I believe it is because the currentNoms is observable however im still trying to find out how to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the Observable to be notified of the values on the Subject. An Observable notifies the subscribers of multiple values. A Subject can multicast those values to many Subscribers.

You can subscribe to the Observable in the constructor of your FooterComponent like this:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 
  this.dataService.currentNoms.subscribe(noms => {
    this.nominations.push(noms);
  });
```

The callback to the subscribe method will be called with every value that is added to the subject.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

I seem to be having some issues accessing the array nominations in my html code:

<div id="nominations" *ngFor="let nom of nominations">
        <img src={{nom.Poster}}/>
</div>

for some reason I get a comment from Angular in my code when I inspect the page, this comment occurs after the above code:
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->

Comment: I am guessing that the nominations array is empty.

Comment: Thats what I thought also, however it seems its not filling the array properly. Adding an image above to show how its populating.

Comment: never mind, just had to do nominations[0]